# How do I update the product stock when the product is purchased?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a product in the database and the stock quantity is 5, 3 purchases were made for this product. How do I add 3 stocks to my product in the products table? current stock quantity should be 8.

[table of products in datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXGJH.png)

[place to buy products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL4y6.png)

```
int fiyat;
int adet = Convert.ToInt32(tbAdet.Text);
int birimFiyat = Convert.ToInt32(tbBirimFiyat.Text);

vt.baglanti();
komut = new SqlCommand("insert into AlisSatis(urunİslemTuru, odemeTuru, firmaAdi, fiyat, adet, tarih, aciklama) values(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7)", vt.baglanti());

fiyat = adet * birimFiyat;

komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cbİslemTuru.SelectedValue);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", cbOdemeTuru.SelectedValue);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", cbFirmalar.SelectedValue);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", fiyat);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", adet);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", dateTimePicker1.Value);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", tbAciklama.Text);

komut = new SqlCommand("update Urunler set  urunStok = @urunStok", vt.baglanti());
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urunStok", adet); -->> this is the code i tried that the stock of the product will be updated

komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Ürün Alışı Gerçekleşmiştir");
vt.baglanti().Close();
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Your `UPDATE` will update **every** row in the table `Urunler`; presumably you need a `WHERE` to filter to the specific row(s) you want to update. I would also, however, suggest doing the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in a single batch with appropriate row/table locking; you would likely be better off with a procedure that handles both and has  `XACT_ABORT` turned on.

Comment: I think your second query will override the first query. Would suggest creating another `SQLCommand` instance for your second query. Anyway, Larnu points out the concept that you need to do.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.